# Making text and a picture centered in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for my html/css/javascript class. I have text and a picture of a bike and I want it all to be centered (the WWF text is just something to hold until I get more bike information). I do not want the text to be spread through the entire page but an inch or so in the left and right. Same thing with the image.

Im new to HTML/CSS/Javascript. I went to w3 tutorial and I can't find the solution.

Thank you guys so much, I seriously appreciate your work.

This is my current code:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #8E8E8E
}

.content {
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #975026;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1BEF0A;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #791519;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<header>
  <a href="home.html">
    <img src="vmoto.gif" alt="vmoto" width="1050" height="163" align="middle">
  </a>
</header>


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Mountain Bike</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Road Bike</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">BMX</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <img src="bicycle-bike-daylight-100582 (1).jpg" alt bicycle width="600" height="400" align="middle"></section>


<div class="content">
  <h3>Interesting Stuff</h3>
  <p>stuff thats really interesting</p>

  <section>
    <h1>WWF</h1>
    <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is an international organization working on issues regarding the conservation, research and restoration of the environment, formerly named the World Wildlife Fund. WWF was founded in 1961.</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>WWF</h1>
    <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is an international organization working on issues regarding the conservation, research and restoration of the environment, formerly named the World Wildlife Fund. WWF was founded in 1961.</p>
  </section>

  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>Contact Us! 123 Main St. Anywhere, NC 99999* | Phone: (919) 123-4567 Fax: (917) 123-8901 | Twitter and Facebook</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: You have an error in your markup (remove the `enter code here` bits)

Comment: The structure is `<html><head>...</head><body> ALL VISIBLE CONTENT HERE </body></html>`

Comment: Hi there Francis, welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference you might want to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as you want your questions to only contain minimal code so it is easier for the community to help you out and figure what the problem might be.

Comment: good to know about the mcve, thanks Barrsosy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to apply **.content** class.

Should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="styles.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: #8E8E8E
        }

        .content {
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: #975026;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #1BEF0A;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="home.html">
            <img src="vmoto.gif"
                alt="vmoto"
                width="1050"
                height="163">
        </a>
    </div>

</header>

<body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I hope this will help other people using HTML. Much appreciation to everyone who replied to assist me and the rules of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```css
div{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
text-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

```html
<div>This is an block</div>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest not to use absolute positioning, it is not needed here at all.

Comment: Seems like `margin:0 auto` would be more appropriate.